# Compound Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a dropdown, where if a certain item is selected a subform pops up (hidden div that appears) with more stuff that needs to be filled out.  What is the best approach to validation for something like this?  I thought about writing a validator (with ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable) but this means i have to take that group of boxes out from the rest of the form so they can be validated as 1 object.

Thanks in advance.

<strike>**Follow Up: I found this that does what I want client-side!  http://foolproof.codeplex.com/**

[RequiredIf]

[RequiredIfNot]

[RequiredIfTrue]

[RequiredIfFalse]

[RequiredIfEmpty]

[RequiredIfNotEmpty]

[RequiredIfRegExMatch]

[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]</strike>
_
Nevermind already found a bunch of problems with foolproof

Comment: Its like I almost need a [Required if(something)] or something similar

Comment: So is the question how do you validate the 'more stuff' that is shown as a result of clicking the item in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, how do you conditionally require it based on another property that is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to extend the ValidationAttribute to create a custom validator. It could be something like this:

```
        public YourValidatorNameAttribute()
        {
            ErrorMessage =  /** your not valid messaging **/;
        }  



        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            bool isValid = true;
            YourClass c = value as YourClass;
            if (c != null)
            {
                if (/** check if the item in your dropdown is selected**/)
                {
                    isValid = /** check value of fields or whatever validation is needed in the 'more stuff' fields**/;
                }
            }
            return isValid;
        }
```

Comment: I did this already, but this means I have to take the set of stuff out of my model and create its own class to take it in as that object, correct? 

Also, how does it know what element to highlight?

Comment: You should not need to create a separate class, just use your existing model. What do you mean 'how does it know what element to highlight'?

Comment: If i use my existing model what do I pass in as that object in the constructor?  Well when it fails validation it highlights a textbox or whatever failed validation.  How will it know what element in what I am testing caused the validation failure?

Comment: The validation class will get passed its object parameter automatically during the posting process, because it will be tied to your main class. All you need to do is add the metadata to your main class to use your new validator: ex.) [YourValidator]public class YourClass { ... The validation failure would be at the class level, so you could have it be in the validation summary, instead of next to a specific field.